# Array Aggregation in Bigquery with Run Length Encoded Arrays

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigtable

I've got a BigQuery table that looks something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|  col1  | cols 2-10 |              col 11             |
--------------------------------------------------------
| event1 | metatdata | [0,0,0,0,0,0,0...1, 30, 50, 43] |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

The last column is an array of int64s that represent event data (the place in the array is important as well as any leading zeros).  Normally ARRAY_AGG would work to aggregate the counts in that last column (which is the end goal of all this), but in my case the data is actually run length encoded (RLE), so it might look like this:

```
[-20, 1, 4, 5, 10, 20]
[-10, 2, 4, 10, 3, 8]
```

Where any negative number represents that number of zeroes.

So [-10, 1] is: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

I'm trying to think of a way to replace the negative numbers at query time with the correct length of array 0's so that I can then feed it into ARRAY_AGG.

An ideal solution would be able to replace any number of negative numbers in the array with the appropriate number of zeros at query time to allow for the aggregation to accurately compute.  A less ideal solution would allow for a fixed number of replacements (or even 1).

So, ideal: [-4, 3, -2, 1, -3, 9] -> [0,0,0,0,3,0,0,1,0,0,0,9]

My attempts so far have used UNNEST and IF statements but I've not gotten very far.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  format('%t', col11) col11, 
  format('%t', encoded_col11) encoded_col11, 
  array(select cast(el as int64) from t.encoded_col11 as el)
from (
  select col11, split((
    select string_agg(if(num < 0,repeat('0', -num), '' || num), '' order by offset)
    from t.col11 num with offset
  ), '') encoded_col11
  from your_table t
) t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This is a very good solution for decoding the RLE but we are left with a string array, the goal would be to sum these array values by index, something like: ```SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY idx) as output FROM ( SELECT idx, SUM(x) AS x FROM ... UNNEST(encoded_col11) AS x WITH OFFSET idx GROUP BY idx``` but first we'd need to covert the ARRAY<STRING> to ARRAY<INT64>.  What would you suggest as an elegant way to do that?

Comment: this answer reflects exactly what was asked in the question :o) will be happy to help more if you will post new questions with your most recent ideas/expectations . meantime, can you confirm that you initial question is actually answered and you got expected output?

Comment: I think the only thing unexpected is ARRAY<STRING> vs ARRAY<INT64>.  I agree the summation parts would be a different question.

Comment: btw, 1) if you need arrays vs string - jusr replace string_agg with array_agg or just apply split on the resulted string) 2) also you can remove `format('%t', ...)` this is here just to represent result in more readable way :o)

Comment: I think string_agg is still required for bringing in the repeat('0') since array_agg doesn't support this.

Comment: add `array(select cast(el as int64) from t.encoded_col11 as el)` to the most outer select and you will get array of int64 - and add alias `t` to the outer `from` - just added those to my answer